# Why does Angular make empty value of number input null?

Tags: angular, input, angular-reactive-forms, default-value

I am wondering why in reactive forms of Angular, input tags with an attribute `type='number'` have `null` as value when they are empty even though in native HTML5 we do never see them have `null` as value.

Input tag in an Angular reactive form looks below.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
   <input matInput formControlName="min" type="number" />
</mat-form-field>
```

Function that defines the `FormGroup` looks below.

```
function createFromGroup() {
  return new FormGroup({
    min: new FormControl('', /* custom validator */),
  });
}
```

In the custom validator, to catch the case when the input is empty I had to find out it is null.

```
const customValidator = (): ValidatorFn => {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    if (control.value === null /*here*/ || control.value === '') return null; // pass validation as exception
    ...
    ...
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it's from the [`matInput`](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/input/input.ts#L91) directive.

Specifically [this line](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/6e1f522d6a50d6f589d069775bc771b5590bff4c/src/material/input/input.ts#L381) that determines the placeholder:

```js
const placeholder = this._formField?._hideControlPlaceholder?.() ? null : this.placeholder;
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into it.
But when I try it with native html input tag, it still shows `null`.